# Does Create Table as Select preserves columns order in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, select, compare, create-table

I'm using following statement to create a duplicate table with data. But i'm curious to know whether this statement preserves the column order of the old_table in the new_table as it is. Since i need to compare some column data of 2 tables later using MINUS statement.

```
CREATE TABLE new_table
AS
SELECT *
FROM old_table
```

Below is the minus statement used to compare. In the following statement cols are queried from ALL_TAB_COLUMNS meta data table.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT cols FROM old_table MINUS (SELECT cols FROM new_table))
```

Below is the meta data query to get column list in the order.

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM ALL_TAB_COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'new_table'
SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM ALL_TAB_COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'old_table'
```

My question, Is column order preserved in both new_table and old_table when copied using CREATE TABLE new_table AS SELECT statement mentioned above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, The New table will have columns exactly in same order as your `select` query.

Comment: Can you give any reference or test that i can use as a proof note? Even though I have tested this and it is working as you said for my scenarios. Want to make sure this does not work incorrectly at any case. :)

Comment: I cant produce any negative test case. For my work I use CTAS on regular basis and it works this way. :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer.